# Save XML to Recordset

Tags: java, xml, android, parsing, resultset

I am working on android, and I am parsing a huge XML file.
so all the time I need to get some data from that XML file, which is making the application very slow.

Is there any way that I can create a data set/record set/result set of the XML file

so that later I can get the data from the newly created set.

and also how to read that set :)

thanks alot!!

regards..

kai!!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, any application that often needs to search huge XML files are going to be somewhat slow.

I don't know what's in your XML file, but if it is suited for storing in SQL database, that might be an idea. Read it once, put it in a database and then searching for stuff should be a lot faster (given the right indexes, of course)

If the data is not too big to keep in memory all at once, you might be able to build a data structure in memory that you can easily find stuff in.

It's really tricky to give a good answer without knowing a little bit more about what sort of data it is, if it is too big to keep in memory and how you go about finding data.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mattias,

well my scenario is this that I am making a prototype of e-commerce application.

actualyy the database is on MSSQL server.
the database contains info on customers, products, orders etc

as I didnnt find a way to connect MSSQL with android, I used the XML to help me in this issue.

I created separate XML of all the tables  and uploaded them. so when in my application suppoer I am searching for a product, I parse the XML file and display the result on scree.

but its very slow.

that is why looking for alternate method or any solution to make parsing fast.

thanks

Comment: So if you got the data from a MSSQL database, it shouldn't be too tricky to put in into another SQL database on the android device?
Then again, I don't know how often you'd need to update your data compared to how often you read it. If you need to update it often, then you'll spend a lot of time on that.
You do know there is an SQLite database available to you on the android device, right?